# VBA Recursive to Search Through Subfolders and Attach Matching Files

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, outlook

I have a macro that works to create emails, attach files.  It runs and I use a recursive function to search through the directory to find files, match them to a field in the spreadsheet, and then attach them once found.  It works and has worked for a while.  However, they have added a level in the directory and now for some reason, it will not work.  I am adding here the recursive section only, as that is where the error happens.
EDIT:  For some reason when running from this new, higher level, it skips all the files that have numbers in the filename.  Those filename numbers are what the macro uses to compare against the number in the field, so when it skips them it fails. So why would it skip them now, but work fine when running from the next subfolder down from the root directory?

Here is a sample directory to show how it looks, with Division being the root top folder.  SubfolderD is where I want it to get to, find the data:

```
Division-->SubfolderA-->Subfolder2-->Subfolder3-->Etc
Division-->SubfolderB-->Subfolder2-->Subfolder3-->Etc
Division-->SubfolderC-->Subfolder2-->Subfolder3-->Etc
Division-->SubfolderD-->Subfolder2-->Subfolder3-->Etc
```

I can adjust the function to search at the SubfolderD and it will find the files.  The issue is that new folders will be added and the files to be found may be in the other folders.  So I need to get it to work from the Division folder consistently.  I have stepped through the sub with F8 and I have looked at the debug print in the Immediate window.  It seems to get all the way through SubfolderC, but then stops and for some reason seems to give up.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

```
Function recurse(sPath As String, strname As String, strName3 As String)

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim myFile As Scripting.file


Dim strJDFile As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim strJDName As String


Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

' strName = Range("a2").Offset(0, 3)
strName3 = Replace(strName3, "/", " ")

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders

Debug.Print " mySubFolder: " & mySubFolder

For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files



    If "*" & myFile.Name & "*" Like "*" & strName3 & "*" Then
        strJDName = myFile.Name
        strDir = mySubFolder & "\"
        strJDFile = strDir & strJDName

        recurse = strJDFile

        Exit Function

    Else
        Debug.Print "  myFile.name: " & myFile.Name

    End If

Next

recurse = recurse(mySubFolder.Path, strname, strName3)

Next

End Function
```

Edited to Post Entire Sub:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Recursive()
'
'
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strname As String
    Dim strName1 As String
    Dim strName3 As String
    Dim strDept As String
    Dim strName2 As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim dteSat As Date
    Dim nextSat As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Test.htm"

        If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
         signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
         Else
         signature = ""
        End If

        Select Case Time
           Case 0.25 To 0.5
                GreetTime = "Good morning"
           Case 0.5 To 0.71
                GreetTime = "Good afternoon"
           Case Else
                GreetTime = "Good evening"
        End Select

        With ActiveSheet
         With .Columns(2)
         .NumberFormat = "General"
         .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), _
                       DataType:=xlFixedWidth, fieldinfo:=Array(0, 1)
         End With
        End With

        With Item
        K = Weekday(Today)
        dteSat = Now() + (10 - K)

        nextSat = Date + 7 - Weekday(Date, vfSaturday)
        End With

        LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Columns("z:z").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        Range("z2") = "Yes"
        Range("z2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("z2:z" & LR)

    For Each cell In Columns("J").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "z").Value) = "yes" Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


        With OutMail
            strName3 = Cells(cell.Row, "b").Value
            strName1 = Cells(cell.Row, "d").Value
            strName2 = Trim(Split(strName1, " ")(1))
            strname = Cells(cell.Row, "a").Value

            strJDFile = recurse("z:\Division", strname, strName3)

            strBody = "<Font Face=calibri><br><br>The form needs to be completed no later " & _
            "than next week. <br><br>" & _



                .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Please Reply"
                .HTMLBody = "<Font Face=calibri>" & GreetTime & " " & strName1 & ", " & strBody & "<br>" & signature
                .Attachments.Add strJDFile
                .Display  'Or use Send
        End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub



Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
End Function


Function recurse(sPath As String, strname As String, strName3 As String)

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim myFile As Scripting.file


Dim strJDFile As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim strJDName As String


Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

' strName = Range("a2").Offset(0, 3)
strName3 = Replace(strName3, "/", " ")

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders

    Debug.Print " mySubFolder: " & mySubFolder

    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files



        If "*" & myFile.Name & "*" Like "*" & strName3 & "*" Then
            strJDName = myFile.Name
            strDir = mySubFolder & "\"
            strJDFile = strDir & strJDName

            recurse = strJDFile

            Exit Function

        Else
            Debug.Print "  myFile.name: " & myFile.Name

        End If

    Next

    recurse = recurse(mySubFolder.Path, strname, strName3)

Next

End Function
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with *what* error you're getting, and on what line? Also, what line is it finally stopping and "giving up" at? Is it possible your meeting your criteria, then hitting the `Exit Function` line before getting to SubfolderD?

Comment: Sorry, it just errors out at the line where it attaches the file in the main sub.  It works when at the lower subfolder, just not from the top root.  It used to work until the users added another subfolder and told me that they will be doing that going forward.  It seems to be doing that...giving up before it hits the subfolderD, but that is the point of the recursive....that it will NOT do that until it finds the matching files.  The error is that just that no attachment could be added because the recurse function did not find a file.  It does not find it because it stops looking.

Comment: Without being able to see the rest of your code, I won't be able to help you... maybe someone else will be able to infer what's going on, but it's not easy when you only see one piece of the picture.

Comment: Sure, I am happy to post the rest of the code, just did not want to confuse things as everything has worked up until now and the only error is with this new directory not being searched.

Comment: My suspicion wouldn't be that it's not being searched, but rather that it is being searched and nothing is meeting your criteria - are you certain that what you're looking for in the folder exists??

Comment: Added entire sub.  Yes, I am sure.  Like I said, when I look through the immediate window data, it goes through everything as it should...then when you would expect it to hit the SubfolderD, it just does not go on.  It just stops.

Comment: When I set it to search from SubfolderD, it finds the data.  So the data is there and it finds it.

Comment: So to get this straight, it hits `Next` after going through `SubfolderC` and it doesn't loop back to the top for `SubfolderD`?

Comment: Okay, so I just ran through it a couple of times based on what you were saying, going through the lines one by one.  So here is the odd thing.  When I have it set to SubfolderrD, it finds everything.  But when set to Division, it finds the files BUT it skips any of the files that have the matching field data in there.  Every file is named with a number at the end.  The code takes a number from a field in the sheet and looks for the file that has that number in it.  So when running from the Subfolder one, it finds those numbered items.  But when from Division, it seems to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to let you know I figured it out.  Everything was working the way it should but it was still not finding, skipping certain files.  It appears there was an issue with this particular problem in Office.  I updated MS Office (all applications) along with Windows to the latest win10 version and it worked!
Thanks again